# Beamer Template - Disable Margins in Title page

Tags: beamer, templates

I am working on an own latex beamer template. Currently, I try to design the title page using `\defbeamertemplate*{title page}{}`. It should look similar to the other pages going from the top to the bottom:

- headline without any title in it (only a Logo on the right hand side)
- a hrule (in head- and footline I realized this by using tikz)
- a background image with basic information on it (title, author, etc.)
- another hrule
- footline without any information but only another logo again flushed to the right

I already got stuck with placing the hrules and the background image. This was my first try:

```
    \defbeamertemplate*{title page}{my theme}
    {
    \leavevmode%
    \vbox{
        \vspace{14ex}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw [] (0,0) -- (\paperwidth, 0);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{pictures/cover}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw [] (0,0) -- (\paperwidth, 0);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \vspace{10ex}
        }
    }
```

Then I realized that I had a margin on the left as well as another on the top of the page. My question ist now, how can I disable margins for the title page only? Or how would you design a title page as described above?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It would be helpful if you could turn this into a complete [minimal (non-)working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). You could do this by providing complete code for a minimal `.sty` file and complete code for a minimal `.tex` file. This way, people can help you out by simply copying and pasting the files and saving them on their machines, rather than having to go through this process themselves.

Comment: The construction of your `title page` template depends of your theme... Can you provide us your complete theme?

Comment: To remove horizontal margins, you can use a `columns` environment with a single `\column` using `\paperwidth` as width.

Answer (score 0):

You could try it with the geometry-package.
Then you can define your standard pages like:

```
\geometry{a4paper, top=2cm, left=2cm, right=2cm, bottom=2cm}
```

For your non-standard page (titlepage) you can use:

```
\newgeometry{top=0cm, left=0cm, right=0cm, bottom=0cm}
```

After that you can simply reset to default by:

```
\restoregeometry
```

Comment: That actually added an extra margin on the left to the headline and footline of all pages.

Comment: With `beamer`, you can't change the `geometry` between frames.